# Есть ли плагин для браузера для перетаскивания и определения координат элементов?

Tags: html, инструменты-разработчика

Очень часто сталкиваюсь с задачей, что нужно абсолютно отпозиционировать много иконок на странице.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Приходится делать кучу скриншотов и в фотошопе измерять расстояние, на которые нужно подвинуть ту или иную иконку.

Есть ли какой-то инструмент (возможно плагин для браузера) для того, чтобы прямо на странице курсором передвигать иконку в нужное положение и получать позиционирование (top, right, bottom, left) от родительского блока с position: relative?

Comment: нет но Вы можете это реализовать небольшим скриптом и плагином [PerfectPixel](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/perfectpixel-by-welldonec/dkaagdgjmgdmbnecmcefdhjekcoceebi?hl=ru) который позволит отобразить оригинал макета, если лень писать скрипт можете воспользоваться [jquery ui draggable](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/)

Comment: Спасибо, как раз то, что нужно. Уже все реализовал, думаю завернуть в расширение для Хрома.

Comment: А как-то плагин реинициализировать можно [ draggableElement.draggable() ] ? Не могу найти информацию. А то я перетаскиваемому элементу динамически класс добавляю.

Comment: Вроде разобрался. Сначала draggableElement.draggable( "destroy" ), а потом опять инициализация.

Comment: Правильно ли я понял, что нужно убрать `перетаскиваемость`? Думаю вполне можно опция `disabled` должна помочь `draggableElement.draggable({disabled: true})`

Comment: Есть несколько картинок. И при клике по картинке добавляется класс и инициализируется плагин. Если по картинке нажали второй раз, то плагин сбрасывается. И так для каждой картинки.

Comment: можно и так, одно другому не мешает, сейчас добавлю пример

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример является минимальной модификацией кода из [документации](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/) в данном случае мы делаем `toggle` класса `draggable` и при наличии класса отключаем `disabled` в опциях метода `draggable`

```js
$(function() {
  $('img').on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('draggable')
    $(this).draggable({disabled:!$(this).hasClass('draggable')})
  })
});
```

```css
.draggable { 
  border: 2px dashed black;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x150" alt="v">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x100" alt="h">
</div>
```